# Simple and convenient way to migrate code from one environment to another

Tags: php, migration, database-migration, data-migration

I am looking for a **simple and convenient** way to **migrate PHP code** from **Staging to Production**. Optionally it would be great if it takes care of **MySQL databases** also.

2 things is important for me: **automatic management of environment-related variables**, such as database credentials and URLs (they differ) and **downtime to be as small as possible**.

What is your way of doing data migrations? Do you use any software?

Comment: This is more a question for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ; look into continous integration and continuous deployment. There are many softwares and platforms to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get lots of opinions about this, so it may not stay here long ;)

We let git handle it here.  Environment is in 'config.php' and is self-aware.  Databases are handled by other means.